# Prevent certain config dependencies from being exported to a config file

Tags: 9, configuration, 10

I have a scenario where I want to import a baseline of configuration for hundreds of sites. New(er) versions of modules recently set permission callbacks to their entities. The problem is that these modules are installed as part of a post-install process and is not (cannot) be part of the install profile. That means that after awhile, when you export config from a running site or master site you can get these added to the dependencies list in a config files config key. The next time you try to instantiate a site, you will get configuration errors as these do not yet exist because the module cannot be installed until after Drupal itself has been installed.

How can I prevent these specific keys from reaching the file? In this case it is related to Role configuration. Is this happening in `BundlePermissionHandlerTrait`? What is the best way to prevent this without causing other issues?

Edit: forgot to mention these sites are created from existing site configuration.

Comment: Deployments often need pre-depoyment installation of modules to prevent the issue you are running into. So prior to the deployment I would run `drush en [MODULE]` so that the module settings can be imported. Maybe this can help.

Comment: It might be different in Site Studio's case - the elements do not exist until you import and rebuild, and that part cannot be done until the site is installed.